# Using $(this) in select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm trying to read a collection from the html5 data-attribute of the input that is converted to select2 to create tags.

This is working when I have one input:

```
$(".tags").select2(
  width: '220px'
  tags: $(".tags").data('collection')
)
```

But I will like to do it more safe using the data of the element itself, I tried this:

```
$(".tags").select2(
  width: '220px'
  tags: $(this).data('collection')
)
```

But it fails with the error:

```
Uncaught query function not defined for Select2 investigador_aplicaciones
```

Do you know if it is posible to use the element itself with a specific selector like $(this)?

Comment: @user182669 - [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) is a jQuery plugin that enhances <select> elements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this instead:

```
$(".tags").each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.select2({
  width: '220px',
  tags: $this.data('collection')
  });
});
```

Because during your call `this` doesn't represent the element in the selector.

Comment: wow! that was a fast answer! I will mark it as accepted when StackOverflow let me do it (8 minutes min mark), thanks!