# Reach data-attribute of select2 select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Is there a way to reach a data-attribute from within a select2?

```
$('select').select2({
  ajax: {
    url: url + '&id=' + $(this).attr('data-id')
    //...
  }
});
//...
<select data-id="1"></select>
<select data-id="2"></select>
<select data-id="3"></select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass a custom param to your ajax url in select2, you should use the `data` ajax function:

```
$('select').select2({
  ajax: {
    url: "zee/base/url" // base url, no params
    data: function(params) {
      return {
        q: params.term,          // search term
        id: $(this).data('id')   // ta daaaa!
        page: params.page
      };
    },

    // moar ajax options
  },

  // moar select2 config options
})
```

As a general note, `this` inside select2 config options refers to the select2 instance (which is an object) and `this` inside the `data` function outlined above refers to the DOM element select2 was called upon, hence the jQuery wrapper`$(this)` has a `.data()` method.

Comment: Thank you for saving me haha! Never used select2 before.

Comment: All you need is to use the console. When in doubt, put a `console.log(this, arguments); debugger;` in your code. It will log `this` in current context, the entire list of current function's arguments and will also stop script execution inside that context, so you can use the `console` at will and find out what you need to find out. One of the more useful `console` helpers is `console.trace()` which will trace the current script's execution so you can see where it starts from.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the document, it says that you can insert the url as a data-type in html select tag like so:

```
<select data-ajax--url="YOUR DESIRED URL" data-ajax--cache="true">
    ...
</select>
```

This url will override the options you have set inside of the function when calling, thus using a different one for each option you set it to in html.

Comment: I have a bunch of selects with different ids so I need to select it within the select2 function. I want to avoid having to do a loop with a bunch of .select2() if that makes any sense. Not possible?

Comment: There is probably a way, I am just not familiar with select2 or if it even makes alot of changes. Have you tried to declare $(this) before the ajax call and store that into a variable, then change the one inside of ajax with that variable so it pertains to the parent?

Comment: I think everything inside select2() are parameters if I'm not mistaken so can I declare anything before the ajax call? That would be great.

Comment: I found this thread, which solves it in the way I want to avoid if possible :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436253/using-this-in-select2

Comment: That was my second approach I just told you haha, I am still thinking...

Comment: How about this post? https://select2.org/configuration/data-attributes I am also trying to understand it.

Comment: Cool! Looks like only select2 standard data attributes though right? I only need the url so it could possibly work. I'm trying it right now, but no luck so far. It doesn't recognize `data-ajax--url="http://example.org/api/test"` Trouble-shooting!

Comment: Thats an example domain, did you replace it with your own domain? XD?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176088/discussion-between-grandiq-and-seabass).